# Nuxt static generated page and axios post

Tags: vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

I have a Nuxt project. Everything is OK when I generate a static page.
However, I need to send a POST request to the other server.

I tried to use both a proxy in nuxt.config.js and just direct query, but after deploy to the ngnix eventually, nothing works.

Please help.

---

UPDATE. Steps to reproduce.

- Create Nuxt App including axios and proxy
- Configure your proxy for other webservice:

`proxy: {
    '/api': {
      target: 'http://example.com:9000',
      pathRewrite: {
        '^/api': '/',
      },
    },
    changeOrigin: true,
  },`

- call this service somewhere in the code:

  `const result = await this.$axios.post('/api/email/subscribe', {email: email})`
- run "yarn dev" and test the service. It works locally properly.
- run 'nuxt generate' and deploy the static code hosting service, for example, hosting.com
- run your page which calls the above-mentioned service.

As a result, instead of making POST call to the `hosting.com/api/email/subscribe`, it calls `localhost:3000/api/email/subscribe`.

Comment: Please elaborate on _"nothing works"_. What is your code attempting to do? Do you see any error messages in your browser console?

Answer (score 4):

Be sure to install the nuxt versions of axios and proxy in your project  [@nuxt/axios](https://axios.nuxtjs.org/) and [@nuxtjs/proxy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nuxtjs/proxy)

after that in your nuxt.config.js add axios as module plus this options for axios and proxy:

```js
  modules: [
    // Doc: https://axios.nuxtjs.org/usage
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    //more modules if you need
  ],
  /*
   ** Axios module configuration
   */
  axios: {
    proxy: true,
    // See https://github.com/nuxt-community/axios-module#options
  },

  proxy: {
    '/api/': {
      target: process.env.AXIOS_SERVER, // I use .env files for the variables
      pathRewrite: { '^/api/': '' }, //this should be your bug
    },
  },
```

now you can use axios in any part of the code like this

```js
const result = await this.$axios.post('/api/email/subscribe', {email: email})
```

it will internally resolve to `AXIOS_SERVER/email/subscribe` without cause cors issues.

EXTRA: test enviroments in local using multiples .env files

you can configure .env for dev and .env.prod for production, after that in local you can use `yarn build && yarn start` for test your app with your production enviroment. You only need add this at the top of your nuxt.config.js file

```js
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' && fs.existsSync('.env.prod')) {
  require('dotenv').config({ path: path.join(__dirname, `.env.prod`) })
} else {
  require('dotenv').config()
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I saw you used 'yarn build' and 'yarn start' did you try 'yarn generate' ? SImply the problem arises exactly only in yarn generate !

Comment: you have two issues, localhost:3000 means you mise configurate the server name in axios or proxy. My code fix that. the other problem is the concept of static vs universal. with generate you has a static version of your site, it's the frontend. The server side is gone. well proxy is serverside code it's normal it not runs in static mode

Comment: Other possible reason why your site call localhost:3000 is because during generate is not disponible .env if you use a CI check if the variables are charged.

Answer (score 1):

By [definition on the Nuxt docs page](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/commands/#list-of-commands) what `nuxt generate` does is: *Build the application and generate every route as a HTML file (used for static hosting).*

Therefore, using [proxy](https://axios.nuxtjs.org/options.html#proxy) is out of question here. Take note that you path is not even being rewritten.

And probably the result you're looking for is not `hosting.com/api/email/subscribe` (wit `/api`), but `hosting.com/email/subscribe`.

Nevertheless, if you use nginx then I don't think you should use Nuxt's `proxy` option. Nginx is built just for that so point your API calls there and in nginx config file just declare where it should point further.